# Complex behaviour with lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to make some strange and complex calculation with lists. I have tried and I have endeavored to get it up and running, but it runs into error. better saying quite difficult to achieve that behavior.

I have following lists.

```
A = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
B = [3,3]          # B list is length of numbers 1 and 2.
E = [10,10]
C = 1
D = []
```

I have this code, but not really working:

```
 for k in B:
    for j in E:
        for i in range(len(A)-k):
            print(i)
            if i == 0:
                D.append(C)
            else:
                D.append(C+(E[k]))
            print(D)
```

***Explaining to achieve results.***

I want to have a for-loop, which enables to append values to my empty list, which looks at **first 3 values** in the beginning of list A by taking `B[0]= 3`, `do something with first 3 values`. And looks at `B[1]= 3`, ie. take the **last 3 values** in the list A, then `do  something to them`  and append them all in order to empty list.

**First 3 values:**

When `A[0]` is selected, I want to have `D[0] = C`, and in case `A[1]` and `A[2]`, `B list` should be `B[1]= C + 1*E[0]` and `B[2]= C + 2*E[0]`.

**Last 3 values:**

When `A[3]` is selected, I want to have `D[3] = C`, and in case `A[4]` and `A[5]`, `B list` should be `B[4]= C + 1*E[1]` and `B[5]= C + 2*E[1]`.

**Expected output:**

```
[1,11,21,1,11,21]
```

I want to get it programmatically, in case changing A list to A = [1,1,2,2] and B = [2,2] or something else.

Comment: Where did Z come from? Can you make sure you keep lower-case and upper-case variable names more consistent? Can you make sure your code even runs? Can you maybe give more clear names to the variables other than a,b,c,E,Z,etc. so the code is more readable?

Comment: Sorry I corrected above code.

Comment: How do the values in `A` come into play? It seems you'd just need either `A` or `B` to determine the first, second and third element. Also, where does that information what to do with the first, second and third element come from? What if `A` and `B` were `[1,2,2,3,3,3,3]` and `[1,2,4]` instead? (What I mean: I see what you want to do, but I can't see the underlying pattern that would allow to make a generic function out of this)

Comment: A values would always be `[1,1]` and `[2]` to start with. it can get to` [1,1,2,2,3]` and `[2,2,1]`

Comment: "do something with first 3 values" isn't a clear problem statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialization of your lists

```
A = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
B = [3,3]          # B list is length of numbers 1 and 2.
E = [10,10]
C = 1
D = []
```

we want to count in `A` starting the first time from 0, the next times from the previous start plus how many items we have used, hence we initialize `start`

```
start = 0
```

We start a loop on the elements `b` of `B`, counting them in `k`, we extract from `A` the elements we need and update the start position for the next pass

```
for k, b in enumerate(B): 
    sub_A = A[start:start+b] 
    start = start+b
```

Now an inner loop on the elements `a` of the sub-list, counting them with `i`,  note that for the first item `i` is zero and so we append `C+0*E[k]=C`, as requested

```
    for i, _ in enumerate(sub_A): 
        D.append(C+i*E[k])
```

To see everything without my comments

```
start = 0 
for k, b in enumerate(B): 
    sub_A = A[start:start+b] 
    start = start+b 
    for i, _ in enumerate(sub_A): 
        D.append(C+i*E[k])
```

Comment: Great and your solution is excellent. Solved just with 6 lines of code! Thank you very much. :)